# SPARK: Reprocess failed records, with new code changes to handle those failures?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-emr, spark-structured-streaming

I have Spark structured streaming job with checkpointing enabled like

`df.writeStream
.option("checkpointLocation", "s3://path/to/bucket/")
.forEachWriter(customForEachWriterImp)
.start()`

The `foreachwriter` is designed to skip bad records, and we are building a dashboard based on AWS Cloudtrail to keep track of skipped bad records, so we can do necessary code changes and re-deploy, but because this bad record's offset is already checkpointed, Spark won't retry to read this object from S3 again, although we have new code to handle those originally bad data.

Reason being we don't want to miss processing any records,
unless the s3 data is completely bad, for which we won't even re-deploy the code changes (and ignore that as a noise).

So, for ex: in S3 json object `record1`, if field `a` is supposed to be an `integer` as per the original schema, then Spark's custom `ForEachWriter` would fail this record as bad, but logically it isn't a bad record, so we want to fix the code to handle that field as `double` which will also fit in the original `integer` as well as `double`, so we will redeploy the code.

Now, when we re-deploy, we want the old bad `double` based record to be re-processed, even though its offset is checkpointed in S3 already.

Spark job running on Amazon EMR, reading from Amazon S3.

Comment: What version of Spark?  Structured streaming was marked as production ready in 2.2

Comment: How do you mark records as bad? Do you throw an exception in the `ForEachWriter`?

Comment: Yes, I throw an exception from the parser/transformer log a error, but this object is checkpointed. So if I redeploy new code and start the spark job again, this object is not read again. I investigated if I can not checkpoint a record, then spark will read again, but there seems no option to avoid checkpointing a object in spark.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I know to re-process after a checkpoint is to run without checkpointing or set a new empty checkpoint directory.  This will reprocess everything.

Comment: I do not want to reprocess everything, that is the problem. Just reprocess only the bad/failed ones